Need help to calculate a distance between two links using sdo_geom.sdo_distance
I am trying to make some test examples for developers with valid and invalid examples using sdo functionality
select '0.05m' as accuracy,sdo_geom.sdo_distance (
sdo_geometry(2002,8307,null,sdo_elem_info_array(1,2,1),
sdo_ordinate_array(0,3,3,3 )),
sdo_geometry(2002,8307,null,sdo_elem_info_array(1,2,1),
sdo_ordinate_array (1,2,2.9,2.9 )),.05, 'unit=M') distance
from dual

Accuracy     Distance
0.05         15680.1608423525
Do not understand how Oracle comes to such conclusion.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
